# How to query date saved as text in bad date format in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am very new to mongodb
I have a database with sale_date and the value is saved as text and the format is "dd:mm:yyyy". Now I want to query based on the date. Like I want to query the last month's entry.
I also have field sale_time and also saved as text and the format is "hh:mm" and I want to query the last hour's entry.

**I want to query from java and also from the mongo console.

One row of my collection:

```
    {  
       "_id":112350,
       "sale_date":"21.07.2011",
       "sale_time":"18:50",
       "store_id":"OK3889-45",
       "region_code":45,
       "product_id":"QKDGLHX5061",
       "product_catagorie":53,
       "no_of_product":1,
       "price":1211.37,
       "total_price":1211.37
    }
```

I have million of entries. Now I want to find the entries for the month of July 2011 or hour from 18:00 to 19:00 in 21.07.2013.

Comment: You've chosen a slightly more difficult way to handle dates as yyyy-mm-dd would have been FAR easier to use as a string as it would sort naturally. Please show your attempts so that we can help. I'm not clear either what you mean by "last hour's entry." You could sort by the time, and grab the top one for example assuming you've used 24hr notation for time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query with a regex matching your results. You said format `dd:mm:yyyy` but the example looks like `dd.mm.yyyy` so I used that in examples

For example:

```
db.sales.find({sale_date: /..\.07\.2011/})
```

This will be ineficient since it can't use an index, but it will get the job done.

It would be better, if you stick with dates as strings to reverse the order to `yyyy:mm:dd` then you could use a anchored regex, which will hit an index like:

```
db.sales.find({sale_date: /2011\.07/})
```

For the hour query:

```
db.sales.find({sale_date: "21.07.2013", sale_time: {$gte: "18:00", $lt: "19:00"}})
```

Comment: Did this help you out?

Comment: yes it helps me but I am sorry I cannot give you vote up cause my reputation is low.

Comment: As I mentioned (and Ben mentioned) If you don't switch your date format, using a regex on your existing structure means MongoDB will not use an index and will search through every document in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient and reliable way to query the for a date range you want given the date structure you have used. A regex style query would scan through the entire collection for example, and if you have millions of documents, that's not acceptable.

You could theoretically create a MapReduce to better structure the data into a new collection. But, that will be more work to maintain (as MapReduces aren't automatically updated, and may make other queries and data fetching involve more steps than you'd like).

Although, if you're willing to do that, I'd strongly suggest you instead just fix your data as I mentioned in my comment to be a standard YYYYMMDD. Even better, you may want to consider merging the time and would be to include the time stamp in the same field:

```
2013-07-21T14:30
```

If you don't though, you can still do the single date query reasonably (although you'd want to index both the date and time as a compound index):

```
db.sales.ensureIndex({ sale_date: 1, sale_time: 1})
```

Regarding the code, it's basically going to look like this:

```
BasicDBObject date = new BasicDBObject("sale_date", "21.07.2013");
BasicDBObject time = new BasicDBObject("sale_time", 
                               new BasicDBObject("$gte", "18:00").
                                           append("$lte", "19:00")); 
BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
obj.add(date);
obj.add(time);
andQuery.put("$and", obj);

cursor = coll.find(andQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it really helps me a lot. I am using compound index for different kind of query but I am not sure about one thing that is how many secondary index I can use????? I am actually using this method as of I am also using the java driver.

Comment: What do you mean? How many? One query will use one secondary index.

Comment: I know that at a time one query will only be able to use one index but my question was how many secondary indexing is possible in mongodb database/collection???? as many as I want or have limit???? Like in my case I want a index only for date, date & time together, date & time & product_id and so on.